# LookUp APIs that can assist with location-based searches particularly in Australia, allowing searches based on zip codes, states, and cities

Tags: location

I'm on the lookout for APIs that can help me conduct location-based searches within Australia. I need them to support searching based on zip codes, states, and cities.( preferably free)

I've explored various APIs, and my search has primarily yielded options that provide results using zip codes, excluding Google's. I'm interested in alternative solutions that might offer similar capabilities with a focus on Australian locations.